# Vertical menu covering h1 content and main content

Tags: html, css

Last week I had everything laid out perfectly fine.  This week I added some css code and everything sunk into each other.  Any idea as to why?  Also, my navbar on top isn't applying the inline-block like is supposed to.  Any hints as to why will be most appreciated.  Please take it easy on me as I'm relatively new to this.  I figure it is going to be something small that I either overlooked or I'm missing.

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> - ePortfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navigation.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

   <body>

     <header>
<nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
    <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
    </span>
    <a href="index.html" class="home">Home</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
    <li><a href="javascript.html" class="nav-links">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
    <li> <a href="navigation.html" class="nav-links">Navigation</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
     
<h1>Navigation Menu Gallery</h1>

    </header>
    <main>

<h2>Vertical Navigation Bar</h2>
<!--Code vertical navigation bar here-->
<nav ID="vertical_nav">

   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<p>The vertical navigation bar was created using an unordered list while removing the ornaments along side of the content.  I chose my colors by visiting W3Schools and viewing 
the color picker and finding 5 hues of one specific color to keep an even flow.  Vertical navigation would be used on websites with single page navigation.  Vertical navigation is also 
a good choice while creating a page with a lot of content where it can be coded to the side of the page to keep in view while scrolling. </p>

<h2>CSS Drop Down Menu</h2>
<!--Code dropdown navigation bar here-->

<nav ID="drop_nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Guitars
        <span class="arrow">&#x25bc;</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Gibson</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fender</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ibanez</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Drums
        <span class="arrow">&#x25bc;</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Tama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pearl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DW</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Amplifiers
        <span class="arrow">&#x25bc;</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Marshall</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Peavy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Crate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa 
<strong>strong</strong>. Cum sociis natoque penatibus 
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque 
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis 
enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum 
felis eu pede <a class="external ext" href="#">link</a> 
mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. 
Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, 
consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, 
dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus 
viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. 
Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. 
Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus 
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque 
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis 
enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum 
felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. 
Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, 
consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, 
dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus 
viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. 
Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. 
Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<h2>Navigation Bar Tabs</h2>


<nav id="tabs_nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus 
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus 
mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque 
eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis 
enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, 
imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Cras dapibus. 
Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, 
consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</p>



    </main>

    <footer>
     <p>© 2020 </p>
    </footer>
<!--<script>
var mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
var navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

onClick( function() {
navBarToggle.toggleClass("setActive");
}
</script> -->
    
</body></html>

   
"```"


@charset "utf-8";


main {
margin-top: 5%;
}


footer {
display: block;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
font-weight: 700;
background: #777;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

/*Start vertical navigation bar*/



#vertical_nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}


#vertical_nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
width: 20%;
}


#vertical_nav ul li {
position: relative;
}


#vertical_nav ul li a {
width: 100%;
color: #7fdbff;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #009, #0000b3, #0000cc, #0000e6, #00f);
display: block;
height: 64px;
font-family: bold Arial, sans-serif;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-decoration: none;

}


#vertical_nav ul li a:hover {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #009 20%, #0000cc 25%, #0000ff 33%);
}



/*Start Drop Menu*/



#drop_nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}



#drop_nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}



#drop_nav li {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


#drop_nav a {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #666699;
display: block;
height: 64px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-decoration: none;
transition: background 0.4s;

}



#drop_nav a:hover {
background-color: #b3b3cc;
}




#drop_nav li:hover .submenu > li {

}


.submenu li {
visibility: hidden;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0;
}


.submenu {
display: flex;
position: relative;
flex-direction: column;
width: 100%;
display: none;
}



.submenu li {

}


.submenu li:hover {
display: block;
}

#drop_nav li:hover .submenu > li {
display: block;
top: 1px;
visibility: visible;
}

.submenu li {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.submenu {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
position: absolute;
width: 20%;
}

.submenu li {
position: relative;
}

.submenu li:hover {
display: flex;
}


.arrow {
margin-left: 8px;
color: #33334d;
font-size: 12px;
}




/*Start Navigation Tabs*/


#tabs_nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#tabs_nav ul {
width: 90%;
list-style-type: none;
display: flex;
}

#tabs_nav ul li {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

#tabs_nav ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
height: 64px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0 ;
margin: 0 -10px 0 5px;
z-index: 5;
text-decoration: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
blur-radius: 5px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
display: block;
background-image: linear-gradient(#2ecc40, #001f3f);
position: relative;
transition: background 0.4s;
font-family: bold Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

#tabs_nav a:hover {
margin-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-right: -5px;
z-index: 5;
position: relative;

}
















/*Start responsive menu here*/


* {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
font-size: 18px;
border: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
padding-bottom: 10px;
background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #ff4136, #0074d9);
}

.main-nav {
list-style-type: none;
display: none;
}

.active {
display: block;
}

.nav-links .home {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(35, 120, 27, .7);
}

.main-nav li {
text-align: center;
margin: 15px auto;
}

.home {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 22px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
color: rgba(0, 255, 255, .8);
font-size: 24px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 70px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 30px;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    
    .home {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .home:hover .navlinks:hover {
        background: rgba(0, 97, 254, 1.);   
    }

}
````

Comment: Does it have something to do with media query?  I commented it out and everything went back to the way it was, but the navbar on top isn't displaying the content... Ahhh.  It's frustrating.

Comment: Looks like you didn't get it back to the way it was before - did you forget something?
Look for a saved copy - it might help if you share it here.

Comment: iAmOren  Once I commented the media query out, it went back to normal, but the media query seems to be the culprit.

Comment: great!  can you share with us the media query code?!?
You didn't show any code.
can you split the HTML from the css? - use "```" in a separate line - one above and one below - a pair for html and a pair for css - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your media query represents a 'mobile first' design - are you viewing your page on a desktop and this is when it is appearing 'sunk into each other'? You need to adjust your media query - as others stated, if you comment it out, your page is viewing fine on desktop.